# Indexing (x <> 4 OR y <> 5)

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I am searching for an index to make the following quick:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    t1 INT NOT NULL, 
    t2 INT NOT NULL, 
    latest_creation_date INT NOT NULL, 
    data_category_id CHAR(36) NOT NULL, 
    value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY(latest_creation_date, t1, t2, data_category_id))
```

The query is a delete and reads:

```
delete 
from mytable 
where 
    latest_creation_date = 0 
    and Not (
           (t1 = 5 and t2 = 10)
        or (t1 = 15 and t2 = 20)
        or (t1 = 215 and t2 = 320)
        or (t1 = 315 and t2 = 420)
        ...
        or (t1 = 415 and t2 = 520)
        or (t1 = 515 and t2 = 620));
```

so it deletes all rows that do not match a few hundred criteria on t1 and t2.

`explain` gives a sequential scan and rearranges the query:

```
Delete on mytable  (cost=0.00..2517652.30 rows=38182950 width=6)
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..2517652.30 rows=38182950 width=6)
         Filter: ((latest_creation_date = 0) AND ((t1 <> 5) OR (t2 <> 10)) AND ((t1 <> 15) OR (t2 <> 20)) AND ((t1 <> 215) OR (t2 <> 320)) AND ((t1 <> 315) OR (t2 <> 420)) AND ((t1 <> 415) OR (t2 <> 520)) AND ((t1 <> 515) OR (t2 <> 620)))
```

Can I create an index that will avoid that full scan?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: such index should be possible https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/indexes-partial.html

Comment: Even if you add an index on t1 and t2, the query optimiser might pick a scan to delete *most* of your rows

Comment: Well, the values are changing, @AntonínLejsek, I was hoping the primary key would be used. But I think it's impossible due to the `<>` comparisons.

Comment: You can probably get it to use the existing index by setting `enable_seqscan = off`  But this probably won't actually be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it should be the same plan, do either of these result in an improved plan?

```
delete from mytable 
where latest_creation_date = 0 and
      (t1, t2) not in ((5, 10), (15, 20), . . . );
```

Or:

```
delete from mytable 
where latest_creation_date = 0 and
      (t1, t2) not in (select v.*
                       from (values (5, 10), (15, 20), . . .) v(t1, t2)
                      );
```

Comment: `and` is missing in your first delete statement !

Comment: Incredible! the `not in ()` lets postgres create a hashed subplan and just boosts performance from 50 minutes to 14 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

I applied  @GordonLinoff's advice, and came up with his second version.

This has reduced my practical time **from 55 Minutes to 14 seconds** (table has 37 million rows). Is this possible???

Here is the corresponding explain output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on mytable e  (cost=107.45..1562955.75 rows=19096080 width=6)
   ->  Seq Scan on data_category_evaluation e  (cost=107.45..1562955.75 rows=19096080 width=6)
         Filter: (((stress_test_run_id)::text = 'null'::text) AND (latest_creation_date = 0) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..99.78 rows=3070 width=8)
```